# 503 server at capacity Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have elastic beanstalk running Node app. Node app sends data to 3 Mongo servers built through cloudformation. Everything is ok until i hit a few million entries in the DB and suddenly I start getting 503 errors.

The logs show this from node app:

```
[MongoError: exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for s2-rs9/XXXXXX:27027]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for s2-rs9/XXXXXX:27027',
  sharded: false,
  primary: 's2-rs9',
  code: 11002,
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for s2-rs9/XXXXXX:27027' }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to enable sharding for your database your shard is false in error message. If the the queries increases you have to enable sharding to balance the increased number of queries.

And you can do this with `sh.enableSharding(database)`

To see commands for sharding, you can do `sh.help()` and this will output you are list of commands with their description. There you can find this enableSharding.

Also keep in mind that you need to have indeces on your myKey before you can do sharding (otherwise you will receive some error about indeces). So if you have not done this - create them before with `db.collection.ensureIndex(myKey)`